# Get full form of abbreviated string in Dart

Tags: regex, string, flutter, dart

I am trying to think of a way where I can fetch the full form of an abbreviated form of a word in the format of string in dart programming. For example, if I have the word "chkn" and after I feed it to the function it should return "chicken" instead. So, the code should be something like as follows:

```
void main() {
  fetchFullForm('chkn');
  fetchFullForm('juc');
}

dynamic fetchFullForm(string word) {
    ....
    print(fullFormWord + '\n');
    return fullFormWord;
}
```

And the output should be:

> chicken

> juice

Note: The abbreviated strings are random and we might not know what it could be in advance. For example, the abbreviated word could be ckn, chkn, chikn, etc. However, based on probability these words seem more likely to be short for chicken.

How I might be able to implement this? Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: you must use some NLP services provided by the big players like AWS, Azure, GCP etc or train new NLP model from scratch

Answer (score 0):

I would use a map for this. For example:

```
final Map<String, String> abbreviatedWords = {
   "chkn": "chicken",
   "juc": "juice",
};

void main() {
   fetchFullForm('chkn');
   fetchFullForm('juc');
}

String fetchFullForm(string word) {
   return abbreviatedWords[word];
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But the abbreviated string might be random and using a map would mean that we have to be aware of what abbreviated form we might be getting as input. So, using a map is not that efficient in that regard. I have also updated my question to reflect this.